# Write in pre-written xlsx format template in python

Tags: python, excel

I am a bit new in python now working in qgis to automates some time. 
I have an excel pre-written template file where i have to add different data in different columns.

```
outpufFile = open('d:/template.xlsx','w')
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    print layer.name() +","+ str(layer.featureCount())
    line = layer.name()
    unicode_line = line.encode('utf-8')
    outpufFile.write(unicode_line)
outpufFile.close()
```

I get this so far but it corrupting my template while I also don't know how to access specific column or row of my file In order  to write at exactly column and row to full my template.

Comment: Have you considered using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) for this, like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31405828/1619971?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Python library that understands how to handle xlsx files:

[openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/), for example.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13833482)

Comment: The question's author, who would seem to be the ultimate authority, would appear to disagree.