# Combine several xlsx files into one single xlsx

Tags: python, pandas, excellibrary

I want to combine several xlsx files into one. However this xlsx files have different number of lines and they have highlight cells. 
When I combine them into one, they appear to be next, without a row beteween the two dataframes, and they also lost the highlighted cells.

Here is the code I have, so far:

```
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
# xlsfiles = [files_in for files_in in glob.glob('*.xlsx')]
for files_in in glob.glob('*.final_2.xlsx'):
    excel_file=pd.ExcelFile(files_in)
    df_excell=pd.read_excel(files_in)
    df_excell.to_excel(writer,index=False)
writer.save()
```

Thanks!

Comment: So really the question you are after is: how do I maintain my Excel formatting when combining excel files using Python?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], at least some example input/output?

Comment: @JeffColdplume, yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

I would start by taking a look at a similar question a user has posted here:

[Python Excel template read and re-write, maintaining formulae and formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223048/python-excel-template-read-and-re-write-maintaining-formulae-and-formatting)